# Use the value of a variable from a procedure in another one

Tags: delphi-2009

can I get the value of a variable declared in a procedure then use it in an if condition in another one , and how please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to either pass the value to the other procedure as an input parameter, or store the value somewhere that both procedures can reach it, such as a class member if both procedures are members of the same class, or in a global variable.  Your question is pretty vague on details, so I can't provide much of an answer beyond this.

Comment: Thank you solved by global variable !